# How do I control line endings conversion with LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: git, libgit2sharp, line-endings

I am using LibGit2Sharp to access a remote Git repository. The scenario is as follows:

1. Clone the repository from a remote URL using `Repository.Clone` method.
2. Fetch from the remote repository using `Commands.Fetch` method.
3. Navigate to a required commit by a tag `commit = repo.Tags["myTag"].PeeledTarget as Commit;`
4. Get the commit tree `tree = commit.Tree`
5. Navigate the tree and get a file blob `blob = tree["my path"].Target as Blob`
6. Get file contents from the blob `blob.GetContentStream()`

As a result I get the file text with Unix line endings, as it is stored in the repository. But I prefer to have Windows line endings in my local copy.

I need to make Git automatically convert line endings for me, as it does with `core.autocrlf` config option. How do I do that with LibGit2Sharp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the [`LibGit2Sharp.Tests/BlobFixture.cs`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/f8e2d42ed9051fa5a5348c1a13d006f0cc069bc7/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/BlobFixture.cs#L30-L45) does prove that core.autocrlf is active:

```
    [InlineData("false", "hey there\n")]
    [InlineData("input", "hey there\n")]
    [InlineData("true", "hey there\r\n")]
    public void CanGetBlobAsFilteredText(string autocrlf, string expectedText)
    {
        SkipIfNotSupported(autocrlf);

        var path = SandboxBareTestRepo();
        using (var repo = new Repository(path))
        {
            repo.Config.Set("core.autocrlf", autocrlf);

            var blob = repo.Lookup<Blob>("a8233120f6ad708f843d861ce2b7228ec4e3dec6");

            var text = blob.GetContentText(new FilteringOptions("foo.txt"));

            Assert.Equal(expectedText, text);
        }
    }
```

Note though, as mentioned in [libgit2/libgit2sharp issue 1195#](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1195#issuecomment-191321522):

> notes, `core.autocrlf` is terrible and deprecated and should very much be avoided in favor of a properly configured `.gitattributes` everywhere.

The [OP C-F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/986720/c-f) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56371757/how-do-i-control-line-endings-conversion-with-libgit2sharp/56371787?noredirect=1#comment99346014_56371787):

> Apparently I have to check the type of the blob using `IsBinary` property and use `GetContentText` or `GetContentStream` accordingly

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Actually, my question was a bit inaccurate, because I was using `blob.GetContentStream`, not `blob.GetContentText` (I have just updated the question) I wonder if that makes any difference...

Comment: @C-F Can you test with `blob.GetContentText`?

Comment: Yes, that was the difference! Apparently I have to check the type of the blob using `IsBinary` property and use GetContentText or GetContentStream accordingly.

Comment: @C-F OK, I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Hi, that is me again. My previous comment was wrong. I was in a hurry and did not test it properly. Now I see that even `GetContentText` method does not translate line endings in a text file (having `blob.IsBinary == false`). I have checked the `repo.Config` and it contains `core.autocrlf = "true"` and also `core.safecrlf = "true"` (whatever it means). So I am basically where I started...

Back to your original answer: do you suggest me to run a given test against the library? How can it help?...

Comment: It can help checking end of lines are properly converted.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the exact same issue.

To get the correct end of lines you need to call `blob.GetContentStream(new FilteringOptions(relativePath))`. The name is not really self explanatory but it will call a different function (`git_blob_filtered_content_stream`) that will return the content with transformed EOLs.

https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/master/LibGit2Sharp/Blob.cs#L56